# Can't play this video on VideoView

Tags: android, api, android-videoview

i try to make stream video apps with VideoView but i got error **Can't play this video** when i try to get url from API, here is the error code :

```
String url_video = vid.source_content;
```

but when i add url manually(copy paste from API) the video can run very well, here is the code :

```
String url_video = "http://117.54.4.124:12180/mvicall/uploads/premium/Eli Sugigi - angkat sekarang juga.mp4";
```

and here is my complete code for videoView :

```
final TopArtis vid = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("video");
    String url_video = vid.source_content;
//  String url_video = "http://117.54.4.124:12180/mvicall/uploads/premium/Eli Sugigi - angkat sekarang juga.mp4";

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mediaController);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_video);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
    videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your code and see if the URL you are getting through the Intent is valid URL or not.

Comment: i mean i want to use String url_video = vid.source_content;

Comment: i use this code for test only 
String url_video = "http://117.54.4.124:12180/mvicall/uploads/premium/Eli Sugigi - angkat sekarang juga.mp4";